# OpenMP calling subroutines in threads

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

The problem I'm facing is as outlined below:

```
module k
  integer :: l,m
end module k

program p4
  use k
  integer :: i,j,omp_get_thread_num,cr

  i = 2
  j = 3

  !$omp parallel num_threads(2) shared(l,m) private(i,j,cr)
  cr = omp_get_thread_num()
  if (cr == 0) goto 1111
  call sub1(i)
  write(*,*) l
  goto 2222
1111 call sub2(j)
  write(*,*) m
2222 continue
  !$omp end parallel
end program p4

subroutine sub1(a)
  use k
  integer :: a

  l = a**2
  write(*,*) 'entered sub1'
end subroutine sub1

subroutine sub2(b)
  use k
  integer :: b

  m = b**2
  write(*,*) 'entered sub2'
end subroutine sub2
```

I've tried to parallelize a serial, (which after parallelization looks as written above). I want essentially the same operation performed twice. So Ideally, I want the output to be

```
entered sub1
4
enterer sub2
9
```

but the output is

```
entered sub2
           0
entered sub1
   923239424
```

I'm new to parallel programming, (my actual problem is a more complicated version of the one I've outlined). Can anyone point out the mistakes and suggest improvements. Thanks

Comment: Agreed with above. What you have is unreadable. Is it Haskell?

Comment: @Adam: Haskell?? No, its obviously Fortran.  Key clue: "continue" statements.

Comment: @IraBaxter ah yes, I just saw the GOTO, too. Thanks for the tip. Maybe I should stop doing such a good job of avoiding both Fortran and Haskell.

Answer (score 8):

OpenMP `private` variables are NOT given initial values, therefore both the calls to `sub1` and `sub2` are made with random values of `i` and `j`. What you are (probably) looking for is `firstprivate` instead:

```
!$omp parallel num_threads(2) shared(l,m) private(cr) firstprivate(i,j)
...
!$omp end parallel
```

`firstprivate` initialises each private copy with the value that the corresponding variable in the main thread had on entry into the parallel region.

Btw, implementing `IF/THEN/ELSE/ENDIF` with `IF/GOTO/CONTINUE` in Fortran 90 and later is considered by many a bad programming style. You should use OpenMP sections instead:

```
!$omp parallel sections num_threads(2) shared(l,m) private(cr) firstprivate(i,j)
  !$omp section
  call sub1(i)
  write(*,*) l
  !$omp section
  call sub2(j)
  write(*,*) m
!$omp end parallel sections
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you should remove `!$omp end section`. gfortran does not recognize this, and it's not either in [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#SECTIONS) tutorial.

Comment: You are correct - just had a look in the standard. I've added them completely mechanically.